# Which of the 4 forces can we practically or theoretically influence?

Tags: forces, gravity, weak-interaction, strong-force

Obviously we have the ability to create an EM field quite easily as seen in an MRI machine.

Do we currently have the ability to control any of the other fundamental forces... One or other of the nuclear forces maybe?

What about theoretically... The ability to generate a gravitational field other than by aggregating mass for instance? Artificial gravity is a mainstay of sci fi but is there an agreed answer it is/isn't physically possible?

Comment: Well on the international space station we "generate" a gravity field, sort of.

Comment: We generate a force on mass but it isn't gravity. Now I know we can say if forces are the same we can't distinguish the cause but I'm talking about actual gravitational waves/field manipulation (as far as I understand the modern view of such things)

Comment: It strongly depends on what you mean by controlling a force. Why do you feel generating an EM field by moving around charged particles is more fundamental than generating a gravitational field by moving around massive particles?

Comment: I'll leave this open to interpretation but I suppose at a simple level: I can burn a tree and run an MRI machine off that. I can run some cows around and power an MRI machine.